# Is there nessary condition for which a graph $G$ has a homomorphism but no surjective homomorphism to $H$?

Tags: graph-theory

Is there (sufficient and) nessary condition for which a graph $G$ has a homomorphism but no surjective homomorphism to $H$? Where the surjective means both vertex and edge are surjective.

Or say if $H$ is a fixed graph like $K_n$, is there sufficient and nessary condition?